# PHP When 2 or more conditions are true (if statement)

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

So I am new to php and trying to practice where users can choose which type of service they want. They can choose more than one service which is why I am using checkboxes and not radio buttons. If they just choose one service (Service A, Service B, or Service C) I can get the correct return in the textbox. When I try to see if the user has checked 2 boxes (Service A and Service B) the return is as if the user only selected Service B.

Here is all my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="service" value="a" />Service A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="service" value="b" />Service B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="service" value="c" />Service C</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$a = $_POST['service'];


if($a == "a")
{
echo "<input type='text' name='txt' value='$1,000'/>";

}

if($a == "b")
{
echo "<input type='text' name='txt' value='$20,000'/>";

}
if($a == "c")
{
echo "<input type='text' name='txt' value='$300,000'/>";

}
if(($a == "a" and $a == "b"))
{
echo "<input type='text' name='txt' value='$21,000'/>";

}

}
?>
```

I have also tried && instead of and and still get the same result.

I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Edited to show entire code.

Comment: Um... I don't mean to offend, but `$a == 'a' && $a == 'b'` can never be true, because `'a' != 'b'`.

Comment: If `$a == 'a'` or `$a == 'b'`, this code will result in two text fields with the same name, as earlier in the code you have the if statements `if($a == 'a')` and `if($a == 'b')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main problems, your first is your inputs need to be an array of checkboxes, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="b">
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="c">
```

Then we can change the PHP to work with the array of checkboxes instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $services = $_POST['service']; // a should now be an array if you're using checkboxes.
  $value = 0; // keep track of all the service values
  $service_list = array(); // keep track of the services ordered

  if(in_array('a', $services)) { // see if a is in the array
    $value += 1000;
    $service_list[] = 'a';
  }
  if(in_array('b', $services)) { // see if b is in the array
    $value += 20000;
    $service_list[] = 'b';
  }
  if(in_array('c', $services)) { // see if c is in the array
    $value += 300000;
    $service_list[] = 'c';
  }
}

echo "You chose the service(s) " . implode(', ', $service_list) . " for a total of $" . number_format($value);
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"txt\" value=\"$". number_format($value) ."\" />";
```

Comment: It is working but for some reason I am getting a warning that my users will be able to see and I would like to fix it and find out what to do so I do not encounter this again. Here is what it says:

Notice: Undefined variable: service_list in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpPracCheckBox\testphps.php on line 43

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpPracCheckBox\testphps.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpPracCheckBox\testphps.php on line 43

Comment: Here is the code from line 43:

Here is the code from line 43:

echo "You chose the service(s) " . implode(', ', $service_list) . " for a total of $" . number_format($value);

Comment: That is a result of the `$_POST['submit'])` not being set. You should only be echoing out the last two lines after a `POST`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand how it is not being set?

Comment: `$service_list = array();` is set inside the first if statement. If it never gets into that if statement (i.e. if it's not a `POST`), then `$service_list` will never be set and you'll get this error. The easiest way to fix this is move that and the `$value = 0;` line above the if statement.

Comment: Ah I understand now. A thousand thank yous kind sir for your patience and assistance. May your day be samsquancharrific!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer (the checkbox to the left of the answer)!

Answer (score 2):

Your checkboxes should be defined like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="a" />
```

Note those `[]` there.

Now, on your PHP side, you can do this:

```
$a = array_flip($_POST['service']);
if( isset($a['a'])) { /* a was checked */ }
if( isset($a['b'])) { /* b was checked */ }
if( isset($a['a'],$a['b'])) { /* a and b were checked */ }
```

Or, more reliably, you may wish to do:

```
$total = 0;
if( isset($a['a'])) $total += 1000;
if( isset($a['b'])) $total += 20000;
if( isset($a['c'])) $total += 300000;
echo '<input type="text" name="txt" value="$'.number_format($total).'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Only radio buttons can have the same name.  Check boxes must have unique values.  When the key value pairs are posted the last pair received by the Browser will overwrite the previous other(s).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="1" />Service A
<input type="checkbox" name="B" value="2" />Service B
<input type="checkbox" name="C" value="3" />Service C

$a = intval($_POST['A'])  // if checkbox was not checked
$b = intval($_POST['B'])  //   intval will make it zero.
$c = intval($_POST['C'])

$values = array(0,1000,20000,30000);
$descriptions = array('','Service A&#x2003;','Service B&#x2003;','Service C&#x2003;');


$value = number_format($values[$a] + $values[$b] + $values[$c]);
$description = $descriptions[$a] . $descriptions[$b]. $descriptions[$c] . '$' . number_format($value);

echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"txt\" value=\"$value\" />$description<br/>";
```